# working with Fluent NHibernate and guid ids

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, guid

We're working with Fluent NHibernate 1.2 and our primary key is a guid saved in a **nvarchar(32)** column, working with Oracle 11gr2.

How can we make this work? (making an automatic conversion...)

Thanks ahead, random programmer...

UPDATE: 
forgot to mention, the guid is saved WITHOUT dashes ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update:

You will have to implement your own IUserType to handle the dashless Guids.
You can read about it here:
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/understanding-nhibernate-type

The detail below is now irrelevant to the question but I'll keep it here for future reference for people to find.

### Using Guids "normally"

In your entity the Id should be of type Guid:

```
public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }
```

And in your ClassMap you should map it like this:

```
Id(x => x.Id)
  .Column("Id")
  .GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
```

This will use the recommended comb algorithm to generate new guids.

or

```
Id(x => x.Id)
  .Column("Id")
  .GeneratedBy.Guid();
```

to genertae new Guids using `System.Guid`

or

```
Id(x => x.Id)
  .Column("Id")
  .GeneratedBy.GuidNative();
```

if you want to let the database generate the Guid for you.

Comment: That's one hell of an issue...You will have to implement your own IUserType. I'll update my answer.